# Jekyll installation successful but 'command not found'

Tags: macos, path, ruby, jekyll

I am trying to install  Jekyll following http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/

```
○ → sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Fetching: jekyll-2.5.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-2.5.3
Parsing documentation for jekyll-2.5.3
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-2.5.3
1 gem installed
```

This seems successful...  But:

```
○ → jekyll
-bash: jekyll: command not found
```

It is not even clear where to look for it...

```
○ → locate jekyll
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.bash_it/plugins/available/jekyll.plugin.bash
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.bash_it/template/jekyllconfig.template.bash
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-1.5.1.gemspec

○ → ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

I am on Mac OSX 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)

Any idea what happens here?

These two old threads do not help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276621/jekyll-installed-but-command-not-found

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146249/jekyll-command-not-found

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that, for whatever reason, `sudo gem install jekyll` installed to `/usr/local/bin`, which was in my user's PATH, but not root's PATH.

Here are the commands I ran, and what they output for me:

1. `which jekyll` - Find the jekyll binary being used by your user

`/usr/local/bin/jekyll`

2. `sudo su` - Switch users to root
3. `echo $PATH` - List the directories root is looking for commands.

`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

If the path from #1 (`/usr/local/bin` for me) is listed here, then you're having a different issue, and #4 won't help you

4. `ln -s /usr/local/bin/jekyll /usr/bin/jekyll` - Create a symbolic link to (path from 1) from (one of the paths from 3)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you used `sudo` and now you don't have the correct permissions. This is just a guess but try installing with `sudo`